# Laravel populate select options with array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I keep getting error

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

when trying to populate select options with the array I've made in Laravel controller. Below is my code. Thanks

Controller :

```php
public function index()
{
    $select_options = array(
        array(
            'name' => 'ALL',
            'value' => 'all',
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Option 1',
            'value' => 'option_2',
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Option 2',
            'value' => 'option_2',
        ),
    );
    
    return view('home', [
        'select_options' => $select_options,
    ]);
}
```

HTML :

```xml
@php
    $old_business_unit= old('old_select_options', $filters['select_options'] ?? null);
@endphp
<select class="form-control custom-select @error('select_options')is-invalid @enderror" name="select_options">
    <option value="">-</option>
    @foreach ($select_options as $select_option)
        @if ($select_option->value == $old_select_options)
            <option value="{{ $select_option->value }}" selected>{{ $select_option->name }}</option>
        @else
            <option value="{{ $select_option->value }}">{{ $select_option->name }}</option>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</select>
@error('select_options')
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
        {{ $message }}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$select_option` is an array, not an object. `$select_option->value` won't work. It will most likely throw the error : "*Trying to access property 'value' of non-object.*"

The correct notation to access the 'value' key of the `$select_option` array  is `$select_option['value']`.

```xml
@foreach ($select_options as $select_option)
    @if ($select_option['value'] == $old_select_options)
        <option value="{{ $select_option['value'] }}" selected>{{ $select_option['name'] }}</option>
    @else
        <option value="{{ $select_option['value'] }}">{{ $select_option['name'] }}</option>
    @endif
@endforeach
```